# Locked Door Number Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

I'm supposed to make a delivery to a crazed botanist.  In case you're curious, the shipping manifest is:

```
Name: Canoga
Weight:  9,723 g
Ref #: 7943
Store Code: 6979
Price: 1,225 won

Name: Khenaizi
Weight:  1,444 g
Ref #: 1331
Store Code: 2342
Price: 4,221 won

Name: Winesap
Weight:  2,152 g
Ref #: 8832
Store Code: 6613
Price: 6,372 won

Name: Ataulfo
Weight:  3,321 g
Ref #: 1443
Store Code: 3224
Price: 2,241 won
```

They told me the password to the front door is:

```
 -15    -13.06        -1    -4.13
   3     -2.67     -2.67       15
 4.5    -12.67    -11.75    -13.5
1.25         1        35       -9
```

When I arrived, I found a screen with a 4x4 grid, and four buttons below labeled

```
A S M D
```

How the heck am I supposed to get in?  If this stuff isn't refrigerated, it'll go to waste.

**Hint 1**

> Determine the sequence of button presses.

**Hint 2**

> What type of item is each delivery?

**Hint 3**

> A, S, M, and D represent basic mathematical operations.

Comment: I can relate Khenaizi, Winesap and Ataulfo to a possible solution, but are you sure that the delivery of Canoga is correct?

Comment: If you mean that you can't answer hint 2 for that one, then I am pretty sure I can -- but if you mean you've got a lot further and made sense of all the numbers for the others, then you're way ahead of me and should ignore this comment.

Comment: @jarnbjo I can relate Canoga to a common thing, yes.  Even so, if you have figured out what the other 3 are, then you know Canoga must be the remaining one.